# Dojo - Json REST call in custom module contructor

Tags: json, rest, dojo

I'm writing a custom module in dojo 1.9 and I have this piece of code used to declare it:

`define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(declare, JsonRest){
    return declare(null, {
        user: 'Not set',
        constructor: function(id){
            var store = new JsonRest({
                target: "myurl"
            });
            store.get('user').then(function(item){
                console.log(item.user);
                this.user = item.user;
            });
        },
        getUser: function(){
            return this.user;
        }
    });
});`

In another file I use this code:

```
require(["modules/demo/demo"], function(demo){
        var x = new demo('7');
        alert(x.getUser());


    });
```

I understood my problem: getUser() function is called before the json/rest call has finished so this function

`alert(x.getUser());`

always return "Not set" because json value is still not loaded. How can I make getUser function wait for it?

p.s.: I'm am sure that json rest request works well because the console log is ok...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such is the nature of Ajax :)

One way to do it, is to make use of the [dojo/Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html) object returned by `store.get()`.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojo/_base/lang", 
    "dojo/store/JsonRest"
], function(
    declare, 
    lang, 
    JsonRest
){
    return declare(null, {
        user: 'Not set',
        _initialized: null,
        constructor: function(id){
            var store = new JsonRest({
                target: "myurl"
            });
            this._initialized = store.get('user');

            this._initialized.then(lang.hitch(this, function(item){
                console.log(item.user);
                this.user = item.user;
            }));
        },
        initialize: function() {
            return this._initialized;
        },
        getUser: function(){
            return this.user;
        }
    });
});
....

require(["modules/demo/demo"], function(demo){
    var x = new demo('7');
    x.initialize().then(function() {
        alert(x.getUser());
    });
});
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6mgwh/

Comment: @michaelramin Ah, I didn't test it, it probably didn't work because the callback in the constructor didn't run in the right scope. Updated the answer, and added a fiddle.